# WPF 'Children' property value in the path '(0).(1)[0].(2)' points to immutable instance of 'System.Windows.Media.TransformCollection'

Tags: wpf, rendertransform

I have been battling this for a couple of days now, and just cannot find the answer.  Hoping someone here can help.

We have an animated keyboard that pops up when a user selects a Textblock Control that requires keyboard input.   The code that animates the keyboard is fine.   But it calls code to adjust the grid that contains the textblock control so that the textblock control always sits just above the animated keyboard.  The problem that I am seeing is that when the page that contains the grid is closed, it exceptions with the 'Children' property value in the path '(0).(1)[0].(2)' points to immutable instance of 'System.Windows.Media.TransformCollection' on this line:
`_AppWindowControl.IsEnabled = false;`

The code that gets called when the keyboard is removed (hidden by "Done" keypress) is this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Animation to hide keyboard
    /// </summary>
    private void HideKeyboard()
    {
            if (_verticalOffset != 0)
            {
                TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
                DoubleAnimation slide = new DoubleAnimation(_verticalOffset, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
                var name = "myTransform" + tt.GetHashCode();
                _mainGrid.RegisterName(name, tt);
                name = "mySlide" + slide.GetHashCode();
                _mainGrid.RegisterName(name, slide);
                _mainGrid.RenderTransform = tt;
                tt.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, slide);
                _verticalOffset = 0;
            }

            Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)this.TryFindResource("HideKeyboard");
            sb.Completed += new EventHandler(HideKeyboard_Completed);
            sb.Begin(this);
    }
```

I added the name registration in hopes that would fix the problem.  But it does not.   If I remove the assignment `_mainGrid.RenderTransform = tt;` then the appWindow closes without any error.

Also, I said the problem occurs when closing the keyboard.   This code was just the easiest to show.   When the keyboard appears, there is a call to AdjustScreen, which creates a similar assignment of a TranslateTransform to the _mainGrid.RenderTransform.   Again, if I remove the assignment, no problem occurs (no animation occurs either).  Otherwise, the same error described above will occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Thanks!

Edit.  Here is the StoryBoard from the xaml file:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="HideKeyboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames AccelerationRatio=".75" BeginTime="00:00:00" DecelerationRatio=".25" Storyboard.TargetName="KeyboardGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0" />
            <!--<SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.20" Value="-10" />-->
            <!--<SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="450" />-->
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="450" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>`enter code here`
```

Also, I have a workaround for this that basically stores the _mainGrid.RenderTransfrom prior to changing it here.  Then, when the HideKeybaord_Completed handler is called, it reverts it back.   This method works.  But it seems pretty hackish.

The crash is an application crash.   Most of the time, we are exiting the UI anyway, so no one ever noticed.  But, as I am adding a new view to the model, it crashes when closing my view and so it doesn't get back to the previous view.

Comment: code seems like bit over complicated for a simple task. could you also share code for the Storyboard `HideKeyboard`. the exception you see is in output/debug window only or it crashes the app.

Comment: For grins, I completely eliminated the keyboard storyboards.  So, the keyboard is either visible or not.  No animation at all.   Also, I commented out the tt.BeginAnimation() calls.  So, all that is left is the creation and assignment of the transform, but it is never used.  This alone will crash the app when trying to close it.  Again, because the transform is apparently immutable.   If I knew how to change that, I would be golden.

Comment: if I understand you correctly you want the keyboard to slide in when the textbox get focus and slide out when closed or textbox looses the focus. I may write a solution based on attached properties, will that be fine with you? I am asking it because in that case we may need to adjust some of your code as well. Additionally if it is possible for your to share a working sample of your code, it would be easier to integrate the same with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to make a Virtual Keyboard kind of behavior

xaml

```
<StackPanel xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <UniformGrid Columns="5"
                     Rows="2"
                     x:Key="dummyKeyboard">
            <Button Content="1" />
            <Button Content="2" />
            <Button Content="3" />
            <Button Content="4" />
            <Button Content="5" />
            <Button Content="A" />
            <Button Content="B" />
            <Button Content="C" />
            <Button Content="D" />
            <Button Content="E" />
        </UniformGrid>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="regular textbox" />
    <TextBox Text="virtual keyboard enabled textbox"
             l:InputProvider.VirtualKeyboard="{StaticResource dummyKeyboard}" />
    <TextBox Text="another regular textbox" />
    <TextBox Text="another virtual keyboard enabled textbox"
             l:InputProvider.VirtualKeyboard="{StaticResource dummyKeyboard}" />
    <TextBox Text="one more regular textbox" />
</StackPanel>
```

for example purpose I have defined a dummyKeyboard containing some buttons. then I have assigned this keyboard to some of the textboxes by setting `InputProvider.VirtualKeyboard="{StaticResource dummyKeyboard}"`, you can assign to all manually or even assign via styles for textbox

InputProvider class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class InputProvider : DependencyObject
    {
        public static object GetVirtualKeyboard(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (object)obj.GetValue(VirtualKeyboardProperty);
        }

        public static void SetVirtualKeyboard(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(VirtualKeyboardProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for VirtualKeyboard.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VirtualKeyboardProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VirtualKeyboard", typeof(object), typeof(InputProvider), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnVirtualKeyboardChanged));

        private static void OnVirtualKeyboardChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = d as TextBox;
            tb.GotFocus += (sender, ee) => OpenPopup(sender as TextBox);
            tb.LostFocus += (sender, ee) => ((Popup)tb.GetValue(PopupProperty)).IsOpen = false;
        }

        private static void OpenPopup(TextBox textBox)
        {
            Popup popup = new Popup() { Child = new ContentControl() { Content = GetVirtualKeyboard(textBox), Focusable = false } };
            FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(popup.Child, true);
            popup.PlacementTarget = textBox;
            popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
            popup.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Slide;
            textBox.SetValue(PopupProperty, popup);
            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Popup.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Popup", typeof(Popup), typeof(InputProvider), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

this class defined an attached property VirtualKeyboard which is of type object, thus allowing you to define data templates as necessary

so this class listen to the GotFocus & LostFocus  events of the textbox and displays or hides the virtual keyboard in a sliding animation.

give this a try, I hope this may help you to achieve the desired.

note that the dummy keyboard is really dummy it does not do any typing, you need to replace the same with your actual working virtual keyboard while implementing the same in your project.

Comment: Have not tried this yet, but am curious as to whether this takes care of animating the page behind the keyboard so that the textblock where the keyboard input is directed is moved so that it sits on top of the pop-up keyboard?  You see, that is actually where the problem is occurring.  By setting the RenderTransform property of the Grid that hosts the textblock to a TranslateTransform so that it can be moved, the Grid now has an immutable child that causes the crash when exiting the app.  So, the keyboard itself is not the issue.

Comment: by setting `PlacementTarget` the Popup will ensure to keep itself near the target control (by default it is at the bottom of the target control). and by setting the `Placement` property we can further define the popup placement ie. Top, Bottom, Right, Left and many more including custom placement. we can further write a code to pull the control to view if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This error can appear if you don't have a TransformGroup defined as the RenderTransform for the thing you are animating. It should look something like this:

```
<Ellipse>
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```